# Understanding an inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, inequality

Let $Q = Q(x_0,r)$ be a cube with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, diameter $r>0$ and center $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $Q^{\prime} = Q(y_0,r)$. Let $B = B(x_0,r)$ be a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$. Let $B^{\prime} = B(y_0,r)$. By taking $x \in Q$, $y \in Q^{\prime}$ or $x \in B$, $y \in B^{\prime}$ we obtain that
$$
\left|\frac{x-x_0}{r}\right|+\left|\frac{y-y_0}{r}\right|\le \sqrt{n}.
$$

I can't understand this inequality? Could you please explain me?

Comment: Did you try to figure it out in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ to begin with? Or maybe even in $\;\Bbb R^1=\Bbb R\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I found for the ball case $LHS\le 2$. I can't see $LHS\le \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Are you sure about your formula? From what I understand, you can take $x=x_0+r(1,\ldots,1)^T\in Q(x_0,r)$ in which case $\left\|\frac{x-x_0}{r}\right\|_2=\sqrt n$. If you also take some point $y\in Q(y_0,r)$ your inequality will in general be false, unless $y=y_0$.

Comment: @N.Bach I see that inequality in the following article in page 515. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11118-016-9592-8.pdf

Comment: Well, that wasn't helpful, I can't access that article. On a side note, I noticed where my understanding was wrong. The "cube" has side length $r$, so I should have taken $x=x_0+\frac r2(1,\ldots,1)^T$ and we get $\frac{\sqrt n}2$ instead, so everything is fine. On a side note, I see the article is dealing with Lebesgue spaces, in which case it would be useful if you specified what norm you're using in that inequality. By default I assumed the $2$-norm, but I'm not even sure now.

Comment: @N.Bach Thank you for your helpful comment. You're right the norm is 2-norm. What do you think for the ball case?

Comment: That if you're able to freely chose $x\in B$ and $y\in B'$ without any other constraints, the inequality looks false for dimension $n<4$. Either I am missing something in the statement, or you forgot some assumptions. Or the author of the article only use this for higher dimension and didn't feel the need to specify it when he stated the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cube with diameter $r$ will be completely contained in a ball of radius $r$. So by showing the statement for the ball, the statement for the cube follows. For the ball, $\left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}r\right\rvert\le1$. This bound is tight, it's essentially the definition of a ball. So

$$\left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}r\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{y-y_0}r\right\rvert\le2=\sqrt4$$

which makes the claim wrong for $n<4$.

So back to the cube. *diameter* $r$ means it fits in a ball of *radius* $\frac r2$. In other words, $\left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}r\right\rvert\le\frac12$ and thus

$$\left\lvert\frac{x-x_0}r\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{y-y_0}r\right\rvert\le1=\sqrt1$$

Much better. Could it be that for the ball you need the *diameter* as well, not the *radius*?